# Sklearn DecisionTreeRegressor - Extend prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, decision-tree

Trying to build a sklearn DecisionTreeRegressor, I'm following the steps listed [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-decision-tree-regression-using-sklearn/) to create a very simple decision tree.

```
X_train = np.array([[100],[500],[1500],[3500]])
y_train = np.array([23, 43, 44, 55])


# create a regressor object
regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state = 0) 
  
# fit the regressor with X and Y data
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The model works fine when predicting values that would be in the X_train interval:

```
y_pred = regressor.predict([[700]])
print(y_pred)
>[43.]
```

However, when predicting, for values higher than the interval listed in X_train, the model only predicts the max value of y_train.

```
X_test = np.array([[4000], [10000]])
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)
>[55. 55.]
```

How could the regression be extended using the X_test data to predict values higher than the ones listed in X_test, so that it predicts following the trend it finds for the X_train interval?

Comment: When you say 'extend', do you mean retrain / refit the model as new data comes in?

Comment: And this might help answer your question regarding creating a interval by using weights to more heavily weight recent observations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029577/how-to-weigh-data-points-with-sklearn-training-algorithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical decision tree algorithms can't really extrapolate beyond seen dataset and to understand why you can plot your decision tree and follow its decision path.

---

Imports

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

---

Tree model

```
X_train = np.array([[100],[500],[1500],[3500]])
y_train = np.array([23, 43, 44, 55])

# create a regressor object
regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state = 0) 
  
# fit the regressor with X and Y data
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

---

Visualized model

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
_ = tree.plot_tree(regressor, 
                   filled=True)
```

[image]

---

Linear model

```
X_train = np.array([[100],[500],[1500],[3500]])
y_train = np.array([23, 43, 44, 55])

reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

x_outside_range = np.array([[4000], [10000]])

plt.plot(X_train,y_train, label='train data')
plt.plot(x_outside_range ,reg.predict(x_outside_range), label='prediction outside train data range')
plt.legend()
```

[image]